# Using Jax-Rs @Get @Post on same method

Tags: java, post, get, annotations, jax-rs

Is it allowed to have @Get @Post or other @HttpMethod on same method of REST service? I know that Jersey return exception, but I want to know only about JAX-RS API, nothing else.

Is it allowed by JAX-RS API to do so?

Edit: I ask this question, because I haven't found anything about this in specification or documentation.

Comment: what do you mean by "allowed"? Did you test whether it works?

Comment: I mean JAX-RS API, not frameworks.

Comment: This does not answer my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JAX-RS specification at http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-spec/index.html does not seem to specify this situation at all.  In section 3.3 it says that "*Resource methods are methods of a resource class annotated with **a** request method designator*" - my emphasis on the word "a". @Get and @POST are examples of request method designators.
Section 3.7.2, which describes how to choose the method that responds to the request just says to filter out methods where "*The request method is supported*".

So I think you've found a gray area in the spec, and apparently the creators of the reference implementation of JAX-RS chose to not to support your use case.

You need to refactor:

```
@GET
public void yourGetMethod() {
    yourMethod();
}

@POST
public void yourPostMethod() {
    yourMethod();
}

public void yourMethod(...
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer that I would like to hear :)